# Can Gradle upload different artifacts to different Maven repos?

Tags: maven, gradle, publishing, artifactory

I'm using Gradle 2.3 and the new `maven-publish` plugin.

Is it possible to control the plugin so that it selects the target repo based on the type of artifacts the project is producing?

I'm generating RPMs using the ['os-package' plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin), which works fine. We also have an Artifactory server configured to act as both jar repo, and a yum repo.

Manually, I can upload jars to the project `proj-dev-local` and rpms to `proj-yum-local`, which works fine for all dependency resolution of rpms and jars.

Now, I want to set up Gradle tasks to publish these two types of artifacts, each to the correct repo in Artifactory.

I understood that the official Artifactory plugin for Gradle is not able to handle several publishing repos, but I think it should be possible using the `maven-publish` plugin, or some other mechanism.

If I only have jar artifacts in one project and rpms in a separate one, I can easily (well...) get it working using the following configuration of the root project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.netflix.nebula', name: 'gradle-ospackage-plugin', version: '2.0.3')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
version = '0.1.1'

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    version = parent.version
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        publishing {
            publications {
                mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                    from components.java
                    repositories {
                        maven {
                            url "https://url/artifactory/proj-dev-local"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    plugins.matching {it.class.name == "com.netflix.gradle.plugins.packaging.CommonPackagingPlugin"}.all {
        ospackage {
            vendor = 'myCompany'
        }
        publishing {
            publications {
                mavenRpm(MavenPublication) {
                    artifact buildRpm //buildRpm is a task added by the os-package plugin
                    repositories {
                        maven {
                            url "https://url/artifactory/proj-yum-local"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, such is not the nature of my software projects - the Rpm projects are almost all also java projects.
In the below test case, I have two subprojects, `jarproject` which only applies the 'java' plugin, and the `rpmproject` which applies both 'java' and 'os-package'.

In the `rpmproject`, I get the jar published in my yum repo, and vice versa.

Is there, for example, some way to modify the `publishMavenRpmPublicationToMavenRepository` task, so it ignores a certain repo?

```
$ gradlew publish  
:jarproject:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication  
:jarproject:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:jarproject:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:jarproject:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jarproject:jar UP-TO-DATE
:jarproject:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Uploading: test/jarproject/0.1.1/jarproject-0.1.1.jar to repository remote at https://url/artifactory/proj-dev-local
Transferring 0K from remote
Uploaded 0K
:jarproject:publish
:rpmproject:generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
:rpmproject:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:rpmproject:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:rpmproject:classes UP-TO-DATE
:rpmproject:jar UP-TO-DATE
:rpmproject:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository
Uploading: test/rpmproject/0.1.1/rpmproject-0.1.1.jar to repository remote at https://url/artifactory/proj-dev-local
Transferring 0K from remote
Uploaded 0K
:rpmproject:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository
Uploading: test/rpmproject/0.1.1/rpmproject-0.1.1.jar to repository remote at https://url/artifactory/proj-yum-local
Transferring 0K from remote
Uploaded 0K
:rpmproject:buildRpm UP-TO-DATE
:rpmproject:generatePomFileForMavenRpmPublication
:rpmproject:publishMavenRpmPublicationToMaven2Repository
Uploading: test/rpmproject/0.1.1/rpmproject-0.1.1.rpm to repository remote at https://url/artifactory/proj-dev-local
Transferring 2K from remote
Uploaded 2K
:rpmproject:publishMavenRpmPublicationToMavenRepository
Uploading: test/rpmproject/0.1.1/rpmproject-0.1.1.rpm to repository remote at https://url/artifactory/proj-yum-local
Transferring 2K from remote
Uploaded 2K
:rpmproject:publish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Mark Vieira, was able to get it all working when I added the following code, in the `subprojects` closure, after the above snippet.

```
//Disable rpm publishing to jar repo and vice versa
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { 
    try {
    tasks.getByPath("${project.getPath()}:publishMavenRpmPublicationToDevRepository").enabled = false;
    } catch (UnknownTaskException e) {
    }
    try {
    tasks.getByPath("${project.getPath()}:publishMavenJavaPublicationToYumRepository").enabled = false;
    } catch (UnknownTaskException e) {
    }
}
```

I still would have liked to see a more aesthetically pleasing way, so further answers are welcome, but at least this solution does the job for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just disable that particular publishing task.

```
model {
    tasks.publishMavenRpmPublicationToMavenRepository {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

Additionally you can give your repos names so the task names make more sense.

```
maven {
    name = 'yum'
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the logic would look like. If I put the above `model` code inside the closure `plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {`, it would disable the RPM publishing for all projects with Java in them, wouldn't it? And vice versa. I don't want that. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: That is unnecessary. Gradle creates a task for each publication/repository combination. Meaning if you declare two publications and two repositories (as you have here) you'll get four publishing tasks. You can simply disable the ones you don't want to run.

Comment: I see. But in the `jarproject`, I cannot apply any configuration to the `publishMavenRpmPublicationToMavenRepository`, because it is not a defined task.  And vice versa. So, applying the above `model` clause in my `subprojects` closure leads to the error `A problem occurred configuring project ':jarproject'.
> The following model rules are unbound:
    model.tasks.publishMavenRpmPublicationToMavenRepository`
I can try to check if the task exists first, not sure, will give it a shot.

Comment: I found something that seems to work, will paste that into my question and accept this answer. Thanks for the help! It works if I do the `enable=false` outside of the `model` closure.